# simple wordpress plugin with some html and javascript

Tags: wordpress

I have an html page which i have to convert to wordpress plugin. my code is simple html and javascript

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculate</title>
    <script language="javascript">
            function addNumbers()
            {
                    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
                    ansD.value = val1 + val2;
            }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="1"/>
   <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="2"/>
   <input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here"               
   onclick="javascript:addNumbers()"/>
   <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

I know basic plugin writing skills such as

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Coding friends hello world
Plugin URI: http://www.codingfriends.com/
Description: Outputs hello world
Version: 0.1
Author: Genux
Author URI: http://www.codingfriends.com   
License: GPL2
*/

function codingfriends_helloworld()
{
//put you form here and javascript here
}

add_action('get_header', 'codingfriends_helloworld');
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
//put your form here and javascript here
```

^ this.

Also, I'd give the [Plugin Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) section of the WordPress Codex a thorough read before going any further.